# Apache POI reading formula value of excel cell

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on application that uploads excel file and insert its value into database.

My code is like following:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
String fileExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(temp1);

Workbook wb = null;
if(fileExtension.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")){ 
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
} else {
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
}

if (wb != null){
    logger.info("Read File");
}

Sheet sheet = null;
Row row = null;
Cell cell = null;

dbConnect();

sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() + 1;

for (int y=1; y<rows; y++){
    row = sheet.getRow(y);
    int cells = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO paycheck(" + 
        "paycheckId, payTitle, payEmployee, payDisDate, payBasicSalary, payIncentive, payAllowance, paySpecialAllowance, " + 
        "payEducation, payTotal, payTax, payOther, payAdvanced, payDeductible, payNet, payDuration, payRate)" + 
            "VALUES(";

    for (int z=0; z<cells; z++){
        cell = row.getCell(z);

        if(z != cells -1){
            sqlQuery += "'" + cell + "', ";
        } else {
            sqlQuery += cell + ")";
        }
    }
    stmt.execute(sqlQuery);
}
dbDisConnect();
```

So when I upload an excel file like following, it works and insert its data to db.

[image]

However, when I upload an excel file like following, db does not get updated.

[image]

May I ask you how to solve this problem, so even if the value of cell is =ROUNDUP((600),2), not 600, it still update db.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is customary for single-letter integer iterator variables to be named `i`, `j`, `k`, ... You should only use names like `x`, `y`, and `z` if they are coordinates. Using `y` and `z` is misleading.

Comment: I used those in other class, that is why I used y and z above there.  Sorry if I mislead you and I won't do it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POI [`Cell`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) class represents a cell, and provides many methods for working with the cell.

When you do `sqlQuery += "'" + cell + "', ";`, you're inserting the value returned by `Cell.toString()`. That value is not explicitly defined to do anything, so you cannot rely on what it returns.

What you want to do, is use the `cell.getStringCellValue()` method, to *"Get the value of the cell as a string"*, as the javadoc states it.

Beyond that, you DON'T want to do the string concatenation you're currently doing, because it makes your code brittle and susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, that will allow hackers to steal your data and/or delete all your tables.

You should instead use a `PreparedStatement`, using parameter markers (`?`), and the `setXxx()` methods.

Comment: Thank you for your tip.  I am working on right now.  I got error when I used  getStringCellValue because that is numeric cell so I will try with getNumericCellValue instead.  I will come back in like an hour after trying those.

Comment: I will read about preparedstatement once I solved these problems first.

Comment: FYI, the recommended way to turn a Cell into a String whilst applying the formatting rules which apply to it is [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html), especially [DataFormatter.formatCellValue](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29). Works for string cells, date cells, numeric cells etc